# Blocked root app can edit database in /data/data/

Tags: android, database, sqlite, root

I want to make an app which can send whatsapp messages.
So i already have an app which can edit the database in whatsapp.
I've used the standard SQLiteOpenHelper.
But i wonder, how the database can be accessed even if I block root for my app.
It still can edit the database of whatsapp. Is it just a mistake of my ROM and device or is it always possible? My ROM is CyanogenMod 12.1 for Samsung Galaxy S3. And if its just possible on my device, however, how can I get it work on other devices (with root)?

Comment: Generally, without root you will not be able to directly touch the sqlite files of another app

Comment: Yeah I know.. That's why i wonder.. I cant test my app with this device if everything works what shouldnt work..

Comment: Yup. Also, be careful. If you do launch it Whatsapp may get pissed and send some lawyers your way...

Comment: How can i make it possible for SQLiteOpenHelper to access root databases? Would it work, if i change my app to a system app?

Comment: But apps like Seebye Sheduler can send whatsapp messages too.. I dont think whatsapp did something against..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. Its because of the file permissons wich are set to chmod 777 for com.whatsapp and its database.. If I want to edit the database on other devices, i simply can set the file permissions with root :)